# Finding eigen values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the matrix
$$
    \begin{matrix}
    -1 & 3 & 5 \\
    -3 & -1 & 6 \\
    0 & 0 & 3\\
    \end{matrix}
$$
I know that the Eigen values are 3, -1+3i, -1-3i and I got the answer by solving the characteristic equation.

My confusion is, why don't I get this answer by just transforming this matrix to an upper triangular form in which case the Eigen values are its diagonal elements. On doing so, the diagonal elements that I got were -1,-10 and 3 (R2-3*R1).
I know that the sum of the eigens should be equal to trace (=3), which is not in this case. But isn't it true that the diagonals of a triangular matrix form it's Eigen values? What am I missing here?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "transform". Some transformations preserve eigenvalues, some don't. What did you have in mind? Elementary row operations generally don't, I'm sure you can come up with a simple $2\times2$ example where you can see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not true as you just illustrated.

I think you are confused with the result that if $$A = PTP^*$$ then the eigenvalues of $A$ and $T$ are the same.

If $A = BT$ where $B$ is nonsingular, we can't conclude that eigenvalues of $A$ and $T$ are the same.